# MailChimp HTML Outlook Conditions

Tags: html, email, outlook, mailchimp

I have spent most of the afternoon trying to find a solution to this problem.

I have a HTML Email template that works fine on most devices but when viewing on Outlook 2013 (the only Outlook version I have access to to test it) it renders like a mobile device. I think I have tracked it down to the Outlook Conditions that i have contained in the code.

```
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="500">
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top" width="500">
<![endif]-->
```

However when I open the email in Outlook, they have been changed to:

```
<!--/*SC*/ [if gte mso 9]>
<center>
<table><tr><td width="580">
<![endif] /*EC*/-->
```

I guess that it stands for SC = Start Comment and EC = End Comment.

Am I right in saying that these are interfering with the Outlook Conditions? Dose anyone know how i can stop MailChimp from putting them in my template?

Comment: Can i ask why there's outlook conditional comments around the table? You should be able to remove them and add a class to the table to resize for mobile?

Comment: Did you by any chance solve your problem? We're having the exact same one...

Comment: @alxscms Unfortunately not. This mystery is still unsolved.

Comment: `          <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
          <table width="100%">
          <tr>
          <td width="102" valign="top">
          <![endif]-->` this code works perfectly fine for me.  I would assume this is not the problem.  Can you show your full code?

Comment: @Eoin - The code works if you manually place it into the source code. However in MailChimp it adds the '/*SC*/' and '/*EC*/' at the beginning and end of comments preventing these sections of code to be executed by Microsoft Applications.

Comment: Where are you inserting it? In a text box? With source code visible?

Comment: The SC and EC is not the problem. Please include your complete template for better inspection.

Comment: My template was perfectly fine, however after more inspection we found out that our client receiving these emails had a middleware altering all emails coming to their network, and modifying conditional comments.

Answer (score 2):

After more inspection on our side we found out that our client receiving these emails had a middleware altering all emails coming to their network, and modifying conditional comments.
If it is any help to anyone, that's great :) it might be the solution to the problem only for us though...

Comment: Do you recall details about the alteration being made? Where it is configured or what the system responsible for this changes?

Answer (score 0):

Not being a Windows user, i don't know what dependency might exist or not, between outlook 2013 and Internet Explorer 10, but this might be relevant to the question:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hh801214(v=vs.60)

> Support for conditional comments has been removed in Internet Explorer 10 standards and quirks modes for improved interoperability and compliance with HTML5. This means that Conditional Comments are now treated as regular comments, just like in other browsers. This change can impact pages written exclusively for Windows Internet Explorer or pages that use browser sniffing to alter their behavior in Internet Explorer.

At least for internet explorer, you gotta `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">`

```
<html> 
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9"> 
  <!--[if IE]> 
    This content is ignored in Internet Explorer 10 and other browsers. 
    In older versions of Internet Explorer, it renders as part of the page. 
  <![endif]--> 
</html>
```

**NOW THIS MIGHT BE A LITLE HACKY** i don't have a way to check that it works, but might be worth give it a try...

```
<html> 
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="mso=EmulateIE9"> 
  <!--[if mso]> 
   Hacky stuff
  <![endif]--> 
</html>
```

Also, maybe try targeting your outlook version the right way... not that is wrong in the question, but in a general way, to each its own.

https://templates.mailchimp.com/development/css/outlook-conditional-css/

> Using Microsoft Office version numbers allows you to target specific Outlook clients. In the example above, ‘mso 9’ is Office 2000, which means you’re targeting Outlook 2000. Other version numbers allow you to target other clients, meaning you can build stylesheets tailored to each version of Outlook.
>
> Outlook 2000 - Version 9
> Outlook 2002 - Version 10
> Outlook 2003 - Version 11
> Outlook 2007 - Version 12
> Outlook 2010 - Version 14
> Outlook 2013 - Version 15

Answer (score -1):

I use this code in templates and it works fine from Outlook 97 until 2013. Starting with Office365, the comments are being ignored, similar to Edge ignoring conditional IE tags in the browser. I don't make any more fine-grained distinguishment of outlook versions, prefer to look for compatible code that works the same/similar in all the old outlook versions.

```
<!--[if mso]><table ...><![endif]-->
<div>Code for all clients</div>
<!--[if mso]></table><![endif]-->
```

I don't use MailChimp myself, but when importing this test-wise, it seems to remain unchanged.

Comment: The code works if I place it through the email client directly. However, when it is pasted into the template on MailChimp and send a test email is sent, MailChimp adds the SC and EC to the beginning of comments. This is preventing the Conditional blocks to be overlooked in outlook If the additional SC and EC were not in the comments, it should work.

Comment: How do you know it is not Outlook adding the codes when it receives it?  Outlook adds a hell of a lot of code.  MC does edit some stuff too, but I've never had problems with conditional comments.

Comment: As you can see `<center>` has been added, I bet that was Outlook